# Ordering RPM virtual packages

Tags: yum, rpm, virtualization

I have following packages, built by my RPM spec:

libevent backend

```
%package -n libfoo-libevent
Summary: libevent backend for FOO
Provides: libfoo-backend
Requires: libevent >= 1.4
```

libev backend

```
%package -n libfoo-libev
Summary: libev backend for FOO
Provides: libfoo-backend
Requires: libev >= 3
```

And the library itself which requires at least one backend installed (both of them also OK)

```
%package -n libfoo
Summary: FOO library
Requires: libfoo-backend
```

Question: How can I control the order in which the backend will be selected by default when I'm installing it with `yum install libfoo`. Currently it seems like it is sorting list `["libfoo-libevent", "libfoo-libev"]` alphabetically and always picks `libfoo-libev`. Is there any way to make `libfoo-libevent` preferred (except renaming it of course)

Comment: Why is this relevant in your case?

Comment: because I have requirement that "libfoo-libevent" backend should be chosen as default. the googling says that it isn't controlled. `repoquery --whatprovides MTA` also shows alphabetically ordered results. What I need some field to put higher priority to "libfoo-libevent" over "libfoo-libev"

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to put libfoo-libevent and libfoo-ev into different repositories and then use yum priorities. Unfortunately priorities are assigned per-repository, not per-package.

Comment: that's does not seem like good option :)